# Domain Health Checker Errors

Tags: https, dns, smtp, plesk, dmarc

I checked my domain in [mxtoolbox](http://mxtoolbox.com/domain/) and found following errors/warnings:

1. dmarc   Missing or Invalid Record
2. https   The Certificate is invalid
3. smtp    Reverse DNS does not match SMTP Banner
4. dns     At least one name server failed to respond in a timely manner
5. dns     SOA Expire Value out of recommended range

I added a txt record in DNS zone for as "_dmarc" and checked it

```
nslookup -query=txt _dmarc.mydomain.com
```

its showing our server IP

Please advise how can I fix all these errors or warnings?

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

@lifesaver That's a tall order without knowing what your domain is to evaluate.

But here's your general answers.

1. If you're missing a DMARC Record in DNS Add it. If it's invalid we need to know what you added
2. Why is the certificate invalid?
3. You need to make it match for smtp (Also it's a good idea to make it match for pop and imap
4. mxtoolbox has a small timeout window on DNS queries use a different tool
5. This is pretty subjective - but it's talking about the SOA TTL value in DNS is outside of their recommended range. Not sure what their recommended range is, but RFC 1912 recommends 14-28 days.

If you need answers to the questions above send an email to [mailtest@unlocktheinbox.com](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/mail-tester/) - It will auto-respond and give you a lot more insight, to what's going on.

Comment: you are making more questions or answering? I am confused